# Interval of convergence of Power Series.

Tags: calculus

> Give an example of power series:
>
> a) whose interval of convergence is $[-1, 1]$ and which is conditionally convergent both at $-1$ and at $1$.
>
> b) whose interval of convergence is $[e, \pi)$.

Can anyone help me with this? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the following series and fill in details:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^n}n\;,\;\;\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left(x-\frac{e+\pi}2\right)^n2^n}{n(\pi-e)^n}$$